# captionsetup inside floatbox messing up image

Tags: floats, captions, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to include images with custom caption label format defined using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` from `caption` package. If I put `\captionsetup` inside `\floatbox` environment the caption and image are not aligned properly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareCaptionFont{red}{\color{red}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{green}{\color{green}}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycap1}{(#2) Caption label type 1}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycap2}{(#2) Caption label type 2}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=default,
  labelsep=newline, 
  justification=centering, 
  labelfont={small,red,bf,it}, 
  textfont={blue}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \floatbox{figure}
             {\captionsetup{labelformat=mycap1}}
             {\caption {Caption for this figure}}
             {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sample.png}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove `\captionsetup` after `\floatbox` the image and caption are aligned properly, but I'll not be able to get custom label for the caption. What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should use `\floatbox{figure}{\captionsetup{labelformat=mycap1}\caption {Caption for this figure}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sample.png}}` instead since `\floatbox` has three (and not four) mandatory arguments.

Comment: Thats it. Fixed it.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: An answer please ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axel Sommerfeldt wrote:

> You should use
>
> ```
> \floatbox%
>     {%first mandatory argument
>      figure%
>     }%
>     {%second mandatory argument
>      \captionsetup{labelformat=mycap1}%
>      \caption {Caption for this figure}%
>     }%
>     {%third mandatory argument
>      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sample.png}%
>     }
> ```
>
> instead since `\floatbox` has three (and not four) mandatory arguments.